# Create table by merging lines based on conditions

Tags: sql-server, variables, merge

Here is the issue I face in SQL Server, I have a table with the following lines:

```
ID  | Parameter  | Value
123 |     A      |   0
123 |     B      |   1.27
123 |     C      |   2.13
124 |     A      |   1.29
...
```

And want to return this unique line per ID:

```
ID | A_Value | C_Value | BothA&C=0?
123|    0    |   2.13  |    NO
```

How could I do this?

Comment: Probably the most common way of doing this would be using aggregates with case. Search for the key words "pivot sql server"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two options - I tend to find option 1 easier to write than option 2, but whichever makes more sense to you. You can test it [here](https://rextester.com/YXLWI3878) (I've added a few more IDs and associated parameter and value entries for example purposes)

## 1 Cross-tab

```
SELECT 
    ID
    , [A_Value] = MAX(CASE WHEN Parameter = 'A' THEN Value END)
    , [C_Value] = MAX(CASE WHEN Parameter = 'C' THEN Value END)
    ,[BothA&C=0] = (CASE WHEN max(CASE WHEN Parameter = 'A' THEN CAST(Value AS INT) END) = 0 AND max(CASE WHEN Parameter = 'C' THEN CAST(Value AS INT) END) = 0 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END )
FROM dbo.yourDataTable
GROUP BY ID
```

## 2 Pivot

```
SELECT 
    ID
    , [A_Value] = [A]
    , [C_Value] = [C] 
    , [BothA&C=0] = CASE WHEN CAST([A] AS INT) = 0 AND CAST([C] AS INT) = 0 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        ID
        ,Parameter
        ,Value
    FROM yourDataTable
) sourceTable
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Value) FOR Parameter IN ([A],[C])
) AS pvt
```

Comment: Looks like Luis got in there with the answer while I was typing.

Comment: Pivot solution worked for me! I didn't try the cross-tab one. Which one would be the most efficient? Thank you for your help!

Comment: The answer to which is most efficient is: it depends. There's good discussion in [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164835/which-is-faster-sumcase-or-cte-pivot) . Similar to the example in the answer in that thread, when I looked into the properties in the execution plan for the pivot example I gave, I could see that SQL had constructed CASE statements behind the scenes - In this case, both methods should be about equal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the technique known as CROSS TABS.

```
SELECT ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Parameter = 'A' THEN Value END) AS A_Value,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Parameter = 'C' THEN Value END) AS C_Value,
       CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN Parameter = 'A' THEN Value END) = 0
             AND MAX(CASE WHEN Parameter = 'A' THEN Value END) = 0 THEN 'Yes'
          ELSE 'No' END AS [BothA&C=0?]
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ID;
```